# How can I identify the input voltage for an unknown device?

Tags: voltage, power

I have this device in my drawer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Some images of the outside are here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is I cannot find a manual or anything on google that says what this is.

Worst of all, it does not even tell me how much voltage it wants or if it is center positive or negative.

Is it possible to figure this out from the circuit board somehow? It seems 5V, but I don't want to risk it and burn something out.

Comment: The 22-20 looks like a diode to me, possibly as a reverse polarity protection. Usually positive is the center pin in the power connector. If you have a multimeter you can probe further. For the voltage 5 V sounds right for such an old device (there is a Fax nr on the sticker).

Comment: *Now the problem is I cannot find, neather manual, nor anything on google what this even is* A hint what it is: POS = Point of Sale, it is the central unit with ethernet, cash register, screen and possibly a card reader.

Comment: Company still seems to exist https://www.incaacomputers.com/products/

Comment: Why do you want to power up an unknown device? It might be some sort of doomsday device. What should  this device do when it is powered?  Perhaps an LED might come on.

Comment: @bobflux I asked them, they said that although logo does look the same that this was their italian division (one man operated) and they had never seen this device so could sadly not help me

Comment: Nothing looks like a screen connection. My hunch is for connecting low-speed devices to Ethernet - e.g., cash drawer, receipt printer, bar code scanner

Answer (score 29):

**TL;DR** most likely it is either a 9V or 12V input, centre-positive

---

Following the power trace from the DC barrel jack:

[image: Power trace running up to the middle]

We see it appears to be a centre-positive jack (the shell appears to head into the ground plane). The centre-pin runs on a trace which heads up to the centre of the board, where we find this little sub-circuit:

[image: MC34063A Subcircuit]

Reading the ident on that chip we get `?4063`, which is undoubtedly an [MC34063A](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) DC-DC converter.

The following is a typical application circuit from the IC datasheet for the MC34063A in a step-down configuration.

[image: Typical DC-DC Buck Converter]

<sup>[Image Source](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf)</sup>

Tracing out the components on your board, while difficult to tell from the one angle, it appears to follow this circuit pretty well, with what appear to be the same component values, almost. The current limit resistor appears to be 0.15R (possibly 0.015R, its a weird code). The inductor appears to match too at 220uH. I can read `122` on the resistor from pin `5` to `GND`, so 1.2kR, and there is a second resistor which could read `3801` which would be 3.8kR which match the divider values for 5V output.

Based on that, the input must be higher than 5V in order for the MC34063 to function as a buck converter. Based on the example design in the datasheet, the inductor size would be functional for an input of 8V to 16V. So most likely it is either a 9V or 12V input.

Comment: The voltage applied to the jack (+ at center) must stay comfortably below the voltage written on CIN (the electrolytic capacitor less away from JP6). If that is 10V, do not use a 12V input, rather 8V or 9V.

Answer (score 5):

**(1)**

You can find the GND (center POS/NEG) by probing with a multimeter. Probe around the capacitors on the PCB, as they all have a negative pin on the GND side and most likely no direct connection to the POS input.

You could also identify a component pin directly soldered to the GND-fill on the PCB visually.

**(2)**

By connecting a variable voltage-source to the POS pin and ramping it slowely from 1V8/3V3/5V0 until the circuit starts operating. I would personally guess either 3V3 or 5VO, as i cant see a pre-reg.

**(3)**

You could also write a email to the company or call them.

If you don't speak italian: Don't worry - englisch is fine most times.

If you didn't buy the component first-hand: Don't worry - most likely they will help.

**Edit** As i could not find a Codice-Fiscale: The company is most likely "gonski".

**(4)**

According to this [spec-sheet](https://digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=372830&part-number=HFC-S%2B) - which uses the same ISDN interface APC5568-5V - i would say with some confidence: The circuit operates from 5V DC.

According to this [memory datasheet](https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=29F400TC&sField=1) i would strongly suggest, that the circuit operates from 5V0, as i can't see a DC/DC or pre-reg on the board.

**(5)**

Please see @TomCarpenter's answer - just excellent.

Comment: At least the site is no more, either the company is gonski or due to other reasons under another name.

Comment: @MiNiMe Hmmmh, just checked my self. Couldn't even find a Codice Fiscale - they are "gonski"

Comment: There's what appears to be an MC34063 DC-DC centre left on the first image. The DC barrel jack trace routes directly up to that.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do:

First check any diodes or glean anything from the pcb. The easiest thing to do would be to probe VCC on the [crystal lan CS8900A](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/76/cs8900a_f5-1160167.pdf) where does its VCC go to? There is probably a regulator on the board somewhere, look up it's datasheet

Answer (score 2):

I think it's likely an ISDN voip gateway, you have 3xrj11 ports for telephony, one rj45 for data and maybe the other rj45 is for serial access.

The internet archive has their site saying they specialise in:

• POS teminals and EFT Server.
• Remote Terminals (Remote Banking).
• Protocol conversion for data transmit.

https://web.archive.org/web/20031225141510/http://www.incaa.it/english/weare.html

Here's a product I think might be similar: https://www.ebay.com/itm/275664478417

This might have been used to connect various Point-of-sale devices (card reader, etc.) to a network.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others: First I'd contact the company for an absolute answer instead of guessing; there's an email address on that label!  They WANT to help you, they WANT you to like/use their product, if not sell you an AC adapter.

Secondly, it looks like the center pin is positive.  You can confirm that with an ohmmeter as the long, silver, solder strip/path on the edge of the board is most likely (99%) negative.

I like @Tom Carpenter's IC identification.  But if all else fails, you can start by applying 5 volts (as with a variable power supply) and looking for signs of life.  If not, then 5.5...  Then 6.0...  Then 6.5...

Determine the higher of the two voltage values on those blue capacitors; write it down.  Then note the maximum value of the IC's input; write it down.  I wouldn't go beyond the *lowest* of those written values.

Comment: thanks, the problem is the company doesn't exist anymore, I tried contacting https://www.incaacomputers.com/ and they told me that Incaa was an one man italian division of theirs (it went bonkers), and sadly they have no idea what this devices does, since its the first time they see it, also Wayback machine doesn't have the website archived. Will try with 5V and see what happens

Comment: Like @Tom Carpenter's schematic suggests, the voltage coming in on the DC jack is usually way higher than the voltage required by the board's components (likely 3.3 to 5); the voltage converter on the board will reduce that.  It is definitely LAN-based after looking up one IC's part number.  Good luck.